# Declaring a different nested number of threads for two separate tasks (OpenMP)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I am writing a parallel code that is exploiting some parallelism at an outer level.  Essentially there are two separate subroutines (very expensive) that may be executed concurrently.  This is a large code, and as such, within each subroutine there are other calls as well as many omp parallel/do regions.  So to execute my two subroutines I want to make use of nested parallelism, so that they can both be called in the outer region as such:

```
!$omp parallel

    !$omp single
        ! Do the first expensive task (contains more omp parallel regions)
    !$omp end single nowait

    !$omp single
        ! Do the second expensive task (contains more omp parallel regions)
    !$omp end single nowait

!$omp end parallel
```

If both of these expensive tasks took an equal amount of time I would not have a problem.  But during the simulation, at each time step, the amount that each has to do changes.  So doing an environment variable for setting the nested number of threads like `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16,8` where I have 16 in the first level of parallelism and 8 in the nested regions (inside the two expensive subroutines) does not work well.  I have a scheme already to distribute the correct number of threads to their respective task,  I just don't know how to set different numbers of threads for the nested level in the respective subroutines.  Of course I could go into each expensive subroutine and all subroutines within those and actually hardcode the number of threads that I would like, but like I mentioned this is a very large code and that is the ugly solution.  I would much rather do this in an environment variable type of way.  There is no information on this subject online.  Does anyone out there have a clue how one could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, but you can set the default team size for nested parallel regions by simply calling `omp_set_num_threads()`. If you call it from the serial part of the application, it will set the default team size for top-level parallel regions. If you call it from within a parallel region, it will affect nested parallel regions spawned by *the calling thread*. And different threads can set different team sizes for their nested regions. So, in a nutshell, you can do something like:

```
!$omp parallel

    !$omp single
        call omp_set_num_threads(nn)
        ! Do the first expensive task (contains more omp parallel regions)
    !$omp end single nowait

    !$omp single
        call omp_set_num_threads(mm)
        ! Do the second expensive task (contains more omp parallel regions)
    !$omp end single nowait

!$omp end parallel
```

Parallel regions spawned from the thread executing the first single construct will execute with `nn` threads. Parallel regions spawned from the thread executing the second single construct will execute with `mm` threads.

Also, have you considered using explicit OpenMP tasks (`!$omp task`) instead of `single` + `nowait`?

Comment: @Hristo_lliev Thank you for your prompt response. What you have suggested is something that crossed my mind, but I didn't have faith that it would be effective.  I should have given it a try before posting, but I thought that the environment variable would override those 'call omp_set_num_threads' statements.  I hope it is that simple, and I will try that now.  Regarding the explicit task construct, I have had mixed results using this in simpler codes.  Do you think that the dynamic scheduling of work done by the task construct would help my load balancing issue without much user intervention?

Comment: The `num_threads` clause (as in `!$omp parallel num_threads(x)`) overrides the value set by `omp_set_num_threads()`, which overrides the value set in the environment. As for the second question, I have no idea - it depends on the kind of work being done.